# Slicing dataframe by Date is done but inputting the sliced to a variable is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

It was done with slicing dataframe through datetime objects. But the problem is that the sliced data are not input to a variable.

The variable should be as dataframe. Of course, when I sliced the dataframe, the type of the sliced was dataframe.

```
df.tail()
Out[37]: 
              Price     Open     High  ...   Change %  A Day %  OC %
Date                                   ...                          
2019-07-10  13435.0  13427.5  13545.0  ...       0.04     1.18  0.06
2019-07-11  13455.0  13432.5  13647.5  ...       0.15     1.75  0.17
2019-07-12  13552.5  13457.5  13645.0  ...       0.72     2.11  0.71
2019-07-15  13545.0  13557.5  13662.5  ...      -0.06     2.65 -0.09
2019-07-16  13440.5  13552.5  13594.0  ...      -0.77     1.23 -0.83


import datetime as dt
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
start = dt.datetime(2019,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df[start:end]
```

the code `df[start:end]` just works fine.
However, when I try `variable = df[start:end]` the console shows

"KeyError: 'Date'"

I want the dataframe `df[start:end]` to be input to a variable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It worked on my end, one thing you can try is to make sure you Date is in the correct format.

if not do:

```
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why but now it works fine with the same code.. strange. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Your `start` and `end` variables are likely not the same format:

```py
start = dt.datetime(2019,1,1) #datetime
end = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #str
```

For the indexing to work as expected, one suggestion would be to also transform `start` to string:

```py
start = dt.datetime(2019,1,1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #str
end = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') #str
```

This way, and assuming your dates on index are also a str, your command should work:

```py
# if index is datetime, convert to string:
# df.index = df.index.apply(lambda x: .strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

df[start:end]
```

Comment: I don't know why but now it works fine with the same code.. strange. Thanks anyway!